# Jest 20 + Webpack 2 + React 15 - Image import issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test a React component that displays an image but I get the following error:

```
 FAIL  test/image.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    [Obfuscated...]/assets/images/sample.png:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){����
                                                                                             ^
    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/image.js:3:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/image.test.js:3:14)
```

The component is very simple

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import image from '../assets/images/sample.png';

export default class Image extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <img src={image}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to test this component using [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/). I have the following configuration in my `package.json` file.

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "./test/jest_setup.js"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "./node_modules/enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss|less)$": "./configs/jest/styleMock.js",
      "\\.(png|jpg|gif|ttf|eot|svg)$": "./configs/jest/fileMock.js"
    },
    "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules"]
  }
```

My `jest_setup.js` looks like this

```
import { shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme';
global.shallow = shallow;
global.render = render;
global.mount = mount;
// Fail tests on any warning
console.error = message => {
  throw new Error(message);
};
```

And finally my test looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Image from '../src/components/image';

test('image', () => {
  const image = shallow(
    <Image/>
  );

  expect(image.text()).toEqual('');
});
```

I was hoping adding

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(css|scss|less)$": "./configs/jest/styleMock.js",
  "\\.(png|jpg|gif|ttf|eot|svg)$": "./configs/jest/fileMock.js"
},
```

would solve it, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Just to be clear. Do you added `configs/jest/fileMock.js` as well? Have you tried to run jest with the `--no-cache` flag?

Comment: @AndreasKöberle yes, they contain

fileMock.js: ```module.exports = '';```
styleMock.js: ```module.exports = {};```

Comment: have you tried using `<rootDir>/configs/jest/fileMock.js` as path?

Comment: @AndreasKöberle yes, no luck :(